# Very simple LIMIT query trouble is blocking me

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code:

```
$page = $_POST["page"];
$pageSize = $_POST["pageSize"];

$toRecord = $page * $pageSize;
$fromRecord = $toRecord - $pageSize;

$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT  $fromRecord, $toRecord";
```

Now, out of 10 total table records, if my `$pageSize` is '3', the first page returns me 3 records, the 2nd 6 records, the 3rd 4 records, and the last one 1 record. I have limited experience in SQL, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LIMIT params are `offset, row_count`. So you should use not `$toRecord`, but `$pageSize` there - and don't forget about escaping it. In fact, I'd rewrite this logic a bit:

```
define('DEFAULT_PAGE_NO', 1);
define('DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE', 10);

if (isset($_POST['page']) {
  $pageNo = max(DEFAULT_PAGE_NO, (int)$_POST['page']);
}
else {
  $pageNo = DEFAULT_PAGE_NO;
}

if (isset($_POST['pageSize']) {
  $pageSize = (int)$_POST['pageSize'];
  if ($pageSize <= 0) {
    $pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE; 
  } 
}
else {
  $pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
}

$offset = ($pageNo - 1) * $pageSize;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, $pageSize";
```

Comment: Ah yes, totally my bad. Thank you very much.

Comment: Additional to that I would add an `order by` to have always the same result. And regarding offsets here is a really interesting article about them: http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset which shows a way doing it without offset (`FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`) and having